# Скачать с github

Tags: сервер, github, npm

https://github.com/stenver/interactive_frontend_development/tree/master/lecture_2/components_example

Чтобы использовать данный материал, мне необходимо ввести следующие команды:

```
npm install
npm start
```

Вопрос в следующем: а как скачать все это в одну папку разом, чтобы в итоге использовать эти команды. 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно [перейти на страницу репозитория](https://github.com/stenver/interactive_frontend_development) и скачать все сразу в виде ZIP архива.[image: скачать]

Comment: На здоровье :) В целом, попробуйте ознакомиться с git — это сложнее, чем скачать zip, но полезно для будущего опыта. Чтобы понять, что это такое и как этим пользоваться, советую почитать https://githowto.com/ru .

Comment: Да, обязательно почитаю

Answer (score 5):

Скачать репозиторий так

```
 git clone https://github.com/stenver/interactive_frontend_development
```

А в остальном советую ознакомиться с

https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=npm

Comment: Спасибо! На самом деле все эти пакеты уже скачала)

Comment: Просто не совсем понятно, что вам нужно. Я так понял, что через npm установить пакет. Ну для начала надо поставить npm

Comment: npm уже был установлен