# Скачивание с гитхаба

Tags: github

Читал как скачивать с гитхаба - http://blog.harrix.org/article/933. Но на странице https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/tree/master/packages/simplebar не нашел нужных ссылок для перехода к скачиванию. Подскажите попунктно как скачивать архив или папку с гитхаба.

Comment: https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar → https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а можно в виде последовательности ссылок (пунктов меню), с помощью которой можно добраться до ссылки скачивания?

Comment: @newbieseeker на странице нужного репозитория зеленая кнопка со стрелкой вниз "code" -> download zip

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLPp9.png

Comment: Что характерно, нашел еще пару подобных вопросов [2016](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577173/1365), [2017](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/716642/1365) годов, но дубликатом закрыть нельзя, потому что кнопку с тех пор переименовали)

Comment: @insolor, кстати, поменяли недавно - пару месяцев назад был старый вариант с кнопками рядом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кнопка для скачивания есть только у всего проекта, а у конкретной папки нет.

[image]
[image]
[image]